# Logic Apps- Unable to Set To and From fields For Dynamics 365 Email Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create an **email** entity in Dynamics 365 using Logic Apps. 
I am filling in the **From** and **Recipient** fields but the when I check the record created in Dynamics, I see that these fields are empty. I know that to and from fields are **activity parties** in Dynamics 365 email entity. Do we have a sample json which I can use in Logic Apps to create an Email Activity with To and From fields set?

Answer (score 1):

As per the product group its not available right now to create and set to and from fields of email entity from logic apps

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, answering without access to laptop. And this is not straightforward answer for you. But just a start to build your own request Json object.

Replace your record guids in below snippet & execute this in browser console or CRM js web resource. Take the `JSON.stringify(email)` at the end & that's what you're looking for.

```
var serverURL = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
var email = {};
email["subject"] = "Email Subject";
email["description"] = "email body description";
email["regardingobjectid_contact@odata.bind"] = "/contacts(guid1)";

//activityparty collection
var activityparties = [];

//from party
var from = {};

from["partyid_systemuser@odata.bind"] = "/systemusers(guid2)";
from["participationtypemask"] = 1;

//to party
var to = {};
to["partyid_contact@odata.bind"] = "/contacts(guid3)";
to["participationtypemask"] = 2;

activityparties.push(to);
activityparties.push(from);

//set to and from to email
email["email_activity_parties"] = activityparties;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", serverURL + "/api/data/v8.0/emails", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "return=representation");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */ ) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status == 201) {
            var emailUri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            }
        else {
            var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
            alert(error.message);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(email));
}
```

In case if you need it, Code referred from this [blog](http://himbap.com/blog/?p=2557).

Comment: Hi @Arun, the snippet you shared is when you are using Web Api from JavaScript.I am using Azure Logic Apps which has an out of the box Dynamics 365 connector

Comment: I know, but there is no direct json object for email creation available. So this is one way to get it. I clearly explained. Read my answer once again.

Comment: I did it already, its not setting it in Logic Apps. But works via PostMan

Comment: Then update your question with Json you tried, issue you faced.