# Unable to get and set activity party list field from Dynamics 365 in logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365

I have created a logic apps which fetches the data from SMS entity. In that entity there are two fields (TO and From) which I am not getting while calling Dynamics 365 List record Connector.
Till now I only got a reference of it by using a azure functions through Javascript or C#.

Is there no other way to get those field directly in logic apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logic Apps- Unable to Set To and From fields For Dynamics 365 Email Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350820/logic-apps-unable-to-set-to-and-from-fields-for-dynamics-365-email-entity)

Comment: @ArunVinoth  Kindly donot tag it as duplicate this question is based on the Logic Apps and the link you shared has nothing mentioned regarding how to achieve this in logic apps.

Comment: But OP (Pratish) confirmed from MS team it’s not available.